# Display value other than 'size' with sunburstR

Tags: r, sunburst-diagram

The following code generates a simple, interactive sunburst using sunburstR (example taken from https://timelyportfolio.github.io/sunburstR/articles/sunburst-2-0-0.html). When you scroll over any section it displays "size", and also wedges are colored according to "size". I would like to be able to manually specify a value other than 'size' that will come up when scrolled over and also that will be used to color the wedges. Is this possible? In other words, I would like to be able to have all wedges the same size, but be able to specify a different value for each wedge.

```
library(sunburstR)
library(htmltools)
library(d3r)

dat <- data.frame(
  level1 = rep(c("a", "b"), each=3),
  level2 = paste0(rep(c("a", "b"), each=3), 1:3),
  size = c(10,5,2,3,8,6),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

knitr::kable(dat)
tree <- d3_nest(dat, value_cols = "size")
tree

sb1 <- sunburst(tree, width="100%", height=400)
sb1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just now seeing this and sorry for the delay.  We can specify another field other than size with the `valueField` argument.  See https://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/616fc81b3bacee0d34a2975d53e9203a as an example.

```
  library(treemap)


  library(sunburstR)
  library(d3r)

  # use example from ?treemap::treemap
  data(GNI2014)
  tm <- treemap(GNI2014,
          index=c("continent", "iso3"),
          vSize="population",
          vColor="continent",
          type="index")

  tm_nest <- d3_nest(
    tm$tm[,c("continent", "iso3", "vSize", "color")],
    value_cols = c("vSize", "color")
  )

  sunburst(
    jsondata = tm_nest,
    valueField = "vSize",
    count = TRUE,
    colors = htmlwidgets::JS("function(d){return d3.select(this).datum().color;}")
  )
```

The prior example also shows how we can change color based on a column in the `data.frame` using a JavaScript function.

Here is another example controlling color https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR/issues/17#issuecomment-228448029.